# How to go a specific textview?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So this is my code in java:

```
 Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.here);
```

I only have one xml file and it has a scrollable layout with 1 button and a lot of textview. I'm wondering how I can go to a specific textview using a button. I only want my button to go to the last textview(findViewById(R.id.here)) in my xml file once it's clicked. How can I do that? Can you please help me? Thank you very much.

This is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.search.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="389dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/here1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:text="HERE!" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/here2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:text="HERE!" />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/here3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:text="HERE!" />

               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/here"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:text="Right here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to go to the last textview once the button is clicked. Thankyou

Comment: do you think you could clarify "want my button to go to the last textview" what exactly do you want to happen when the button is pressed?

Comment: For example, I have a scrollview inside that i have linearlayout which have a button and a lot of text view. I have 10 different textview with different text inside of it. Once my button is clicked, I want it to go to the 10th textview. Thankyouu

Comment: can you share your code and your xml that contain the linearlayout ( button and textview)

Comment: I edited my question already. Thankyouu

Answer (score 2):

you can scroll to any widget in scroll view by this code:(kotlin syntax, if you want  change to Java):

```
fun scrollToView(scrollViewParent: ScrollView, view: View) {
    val childOffset = Point()
    getDeepChildOffset(scrollViewParent, view.parent, view, childOffset)
    scrollViewParent.smoothScrollTo(0, childOffset.y)
}

private fun getDeepChildOffset(mainParent: ViewGroup, parent: ViewParent, child: View, accumulatedOffset: Point) {
    val parentGroup = parent as ViewGroup
    accumulatedOffset.x += child.left
    accumulatedOffset.y += child.top
    if (parentGroup == mainParent) {
        return
    }
    getDeepChildOffset(mainParent, parentGroup.parent, parentGroup, accumulatedOffset)
}
```

then you just call `scrollToView` by each view that you want to scroll to it

Answer (score 1):

im still not understand you very well check this answer about what i understand from you

```
Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.here);
ScrollView scrollv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),txt1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     scrollv.scrollTo(0, scrollv.getBottom());
```

now if that not your answer try to explain me more

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried your code and it has an error in the getActivity part. Btw thankyou

Comment: It's not working. I just want my app to automatically scroll to go to a specific textview once the button is clicked.

Comment: then try this    ,, Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),txt1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: do u mean -- u need to make the scroll go to the last TextView not to control the textview itself ?!

Comment: In my xml, I have a button and 4  textview. Once the button is clicked, I want my app to automatically scroll and go to a specific textview which is the 4th textview(id=here).

Comment: Yes sir. That's what i want

Comment: I try the getApplicationContext and it works. It shows "Right here" which is my last text view. But I want is to automatically scroll my app to the location of the textview. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183404/discussion-between-hassan-badawi-and-gerald-manibale).